# Proguard obfuscation did't work for Android App

Tags: android, proguard

For my sample app,this is my build.gradle.

```
{
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.credila.testndk"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
}
```

but,don't know why my code is not get obfuscated.?that means after decompiling all `class's`, `variable's`, constant's` name remains same as i was given to them but i does't want it. Please help me out.

Comment: are you sure you build a release configuration?

Comment: whats in proguard-rules.pro?

Comment: @VladMatvienko ,yes i am using build configuration

Comment: @AmrutBidri nothing

Comment: then you should add required proguard rules to it

Comment: @AmrutBidri i read about proguard manual , keep does not work for me,i want my all classes to get obfuscated,so what should i do.

Comment: **which** exactly build configuration?

Comment: release build,create singed apk.then check right.

Answer (score 1):

> but,don't know why my code is not get obfuscated

Proguard kicks in for release builds only. It will not be used for debug builds, so ensure you peek proper APK.

**EDIT**

Your gradle contains

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

and while `proguard-rules.pro` may be empty, there're default rules in 'proguard-android.txt' (in `<SDK>\tools\proguard` folder) that will affect your project. Some classes must not be obfuscated as they need to be accessible by framework (i.e. subclass of `android.view.View`, `android.app.Activity`. That's must be done because if your i.e. `onCreate()` is renamed then Android framework would fail to find the right method to call and there's no way for it to figure out that it is now named 'a()` (and if that'd be the information about that stored in the app, then the whole obfuscation would be pretty pointless).

Check the defaults and if you need some members to be obfuscated move it to separate class or restructure your code

Comment: i tested it with release build.

Comment: i think proguard does't work for activity.when adding other classes it's get successfully obfuscated.